Helm loop with specific values
I want to build multiple KafkaConnector template from values.yaml, but with specic map
the values.yaml instance :
Definition:
  Information:
    - db.user:
        name: aaa
        key: bbb
    - db.secret:
        name: aaa
        key: ccc
    - db.host: hosntame
    - db.port: 1234
  Information1:
    - db.user:
        name: zzz
        key: yyy
    - db.secret:
        name: zzz
        key: vvv
    - db.host: hosntame1
    - db.port: 1235

connector.yaml file
{{- range .Value.Definition }}
---
apiVersion: {{ $.Values.apiVersion }}
kind: KafkaConnector
metadata:
  name: {{ include "common.names.fullname" $ }}-{{ .name }}    
spec:
  class: need
  config: 
  {{ range $k, $v := .Value }}
  {{ $k }}:
    {{ if eq  $k "db.secret" }}
    ${secrets:{{ $v.name }}/{{ $v.value }}}
    {{ else }}
    {{ $v.value }}
  {{ end }}
{{ end }}
{{ end }}

At the end, the output I would like something like that :
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: KafkaConnector
metadata:
  name: connect-Information
spec:
  class: need
  config:
    db.user: bbb
    db.secret: ${secrets:aaa/ccc}
    db.hostname: hostname
    db.port: 1234

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: KafkaConnector
metadata:
  name: connect-Information1
spec:
  class: need
  config:
    db.user: yyy
    db.secret: ${secrets:zzz/vvv}
    db.hostname: hostname1
    db.port: 1235

I succced to loop over one time with only information, but I cannot to loop over two key information/information1
because, I need to make two loop.

Why would you want to have Information, Information1 (and so on) as lists and Definition as a dict? It should be vice versa to be efficient and suit your needs.

it is just a model, I can change, I juste would like to success my loop and get my final template

To solve this problem, you need to organize your values into a suitable data structure. Then, you should use a range to iterate through this list or dictionary appropriately.
Here is a solution:
values.yaml
Definition:
  Information:
    db.user:
      name: aaa
      key: bbb
    db.secret:
      name: aaa
      key: ccc
    db.host: hosntame
    db.port: 1234
  Information1:
    db.user:
      name: zzz
      key: yyy
    db.secret:
      name: zzz
      key: vvv
    db.host: hosntame1
    db.port: 1235

Note that in the values.yaml, a dictionary is used under Definition.Information instead of the original list structure. This change was made because the original structure had non-uniform keys, making the use of a list unnecessary. Using a dictionary is a better approach.
connector.yaml
{{- range $infoKey, $infoVal := .Values.Definition }}
---
apiVersion: {{ $.Values.apiVersion }}
kind: KafkaConnector
metadata:
  name: test-{{ $infoKey }}    
spec:
  class: need
  config:  
    {{- range $k, $v := $infoVal }}
    {{- if eq $k "db.secret" }}
    {{ $k }}: ${secrets: {{ $v.name }}/{{ $v.key }}}
    {{- else if eq $k "db.user" }}
    {{ $k }}: {{ $v.key }}
    {{- else }}
    {{ $k }}: {{ $v }}
    {{- end }}
    {{- end }}
{{- end }}

Additionally, you need to be mindful of using the "-" symbol within {{- }} to remove unnecessary whitespace characters appropriately.
output
---
apiVersion: 
kind: KafkaConnector
metadata:
  name: test-Information    
spec:
  class: need
  config:
    db.host: hosntame
    db.port: 1234
    db.secret: ${secrets: aaa/ccc}
    db.user: bbb
---
apiVersion: 
kind: KafkaConnector
metadata:
  name: test-Information1    
spec:
  class: need
  config:
    db.host: hosntame1
    db.port: 1235
    db.secret: ${secrets: zzz/vvv}
    db.user: yyy

ps: helm doc: In addition to lists and tuples, range can be used to iterate over collections that have a key and a value (like a map or dict).
